# I m getting a HTTP error 500 even after adding ojdbc14.jar file

Tags: html, sql, jsp, jdbc

I tried adding the `ojdbc14.jar` file but I am getting: `HTTP error 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException :  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` while doing my code for jsp.

```
`<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page Successful</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    String username = request.getParameter("username");    
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from login where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'");
    if (rs.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
    //out.println("welcome " + userid);
    //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
    response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Is the connector jar file added to WEB-INF/lib folder as well?
Copy the connector jar to the lib folder and it should work.

Comment: yes i did adding it too but still it didnt work... n which connector you are talking about??

Comment: By connector, I mean ojdbc14.jar. Could you please share the complete error stack trace?

Comment: i got the reason behind it. The driver class was different than the actual one like oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is included normally. But for me, it needed oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver. Thank u any ways...

Answer (score 0):

Many a times, the driver class can be of type oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver instead of oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. So whenever we choose for the driver the path for it gets set. Check the path in the summary before including it in the project.